# Как сделать пустой DataFrame по дням, времени и секундам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как сделать пустой DataFrame от понедельника до пятницы (скажем от 202010 до 202011), с 10 до 14, с временем в секундах?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['NaN'], 'Sec': ['NaN'],'1': ['NaN'], '2': ['NaN']})
```

Результат:

```
...
Date      Sec    1    2
20201011 131007 NaN  NaN
20201011 131008 NaN  NaN
20201011 131009 NaN  NaN
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137277/how-can-i-make-a-python-numpy-arange-of-datetime

Comment: что значит с 10 до 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
In [120]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range('2020-12-07', '2020-12-12', freq="1S")})

In [121]: df
Out[121]: 
                      Date
0      2020-12-07 00:00:00
1      2020-12-07 00:00:01
2      2020-12-07 00:00:02
3      2020-12-07 00:00:03
4      2020-12-07 00:00:04
...                    ...
431996 2020-12-11 23:59:56
431997 2020-12-11 23:59:57
431998 2020-12-11 23:59:58
431999 2020-12-11 23:59:59
432000 2020-12-12 00:00:00

[432001 rows x 1 columns]

In [122]: df.dtypes
Out[122]: 
Date    datetime64[ns]   # <--- NOTE!
dtype: object
```

а дальше фильтруйте строки по времени как вам нужно и добавляйте новые столбцы...